# Do you have to install newer Debian versions to use newer software?

Tags: linux, debian, dpkg, glibc

I am still on Debian Buster, which has old libraries in its repository.

I am unable to use newer software, because for example, they require a libc.so.6 library with version GLIBC_2.30, which doesn't exist in the buster main repository.

People write that you shouldn't mix and match packages from different repositories, so does that mean I have to install a newer Debian version altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when you use an older version of an operating system, you're limited to older software and libraries that perhaps were current at the time of the OS version's release. In some cases you can install non-conflicting newer versions of some libraries, but by and large support goes the other way -- old libraries are usually provided for newer operating systems rather than the other way around.

A newer version is highly recommended. Debian Buster stopped getting security update in June 2022 (though I believe it gets LTS for a while longer).